# How do I change the size of the points based on the value of the column using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using ggplot on rstudio, I am trying to change the size of the point of my scatter plot based on the log of the pvalue column. This is how my matrix looks like.

```
head(BDpvalue)
            id           t-value               pvalue    mean.f    mean.m          Gene Chromosome
1 ILMN_1212619   3.0512842692996  0.00938046962249251  85.40076  80.02744        Mfap3l          8
2 ILMN_1212693  3.40887110529531  0.00452088152864021  87.28189  82.89533         Snx33          9
3 ILMN_1213324 -4.54750670298688 0.000414140589714275  82.68924  88.81421        Zfp961          8
4 ILMN_1213848 -3.63180275429357  0.00246745595956587 421.61780 469.51845      Itgb1bp1         12
5 ILMN_1213961  2.97573716869553  0.00960659647288939  82.01748  78.44721         Copg2          6
6 ILMN_1214482 -4.23666060706341 0.000813240203181102 136.55021 153.34681 2700081O15Rik         19
```

>

The code to change the size based on the log of the pvalue column seems correct to me, but for some reason I am not seeing a change in the graph, this is the code that I used.

```
ggplot(BDpvalue, aes(x=(log(mean.m,10)+log(mean.f,10))/2,
y= log(mean.f/mean.m,10),color=Chromosome) + geom_point(aes(size=(-log(pvalue,10))))
```

Comment: please post a reproducible dataset with `dput()`

Comment: Your parentheses are wrong; `geom_point` should be outside of `ggplot`: `ggplot(BDpvalue, aes(x = (log(mean.m, 10) + log(mean.f, 10))/2,
                     y = log(mean.f/mean.m,10), color = Chromosome)) + 
           geom_point(aes(size = -log(pvalue,10)))`

Comment: I tried using the code from above and got an error message:
Error in Math.factor(pvalue, 10) : ‘log’ not meaningful for factors

Comment: try `BDpvalue$pvalue <- as.numeric(BDpvalue$pvalue)`

Comment: @passiflora, `BDpvalue$pvalue <- as.numeric(BDpvalue$pvalue)` will return the factor levels. To get the original numerical values of the factor use `BDpvalue$pvalue <-as.numeric(as.character(BDpvalue$pvalue))`

Comment: *based on the log of the pvalue column*: point sizes are **positive**. (You are aware that p-values are in  the interval `[0, 1]`, aren't you?)